# What is that method by which a king ruling his subjects may, in consequence of it, obtain great blessedness and eternal fame?'

Tags: kings

Many kings such as Bhagiratha, Rama, Srinjaya, Bharata, and Rantideva earned eternal fame.

What is that method by which a king ruling his subjects may, in consequence of it, obtain great blessedness and eternal fame?

Comment: Bhishma explained in detail all such things to Yuddhisthira.

Comment: where did he do it? write an answer cited with evidence please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the following provides an answer. But the elaborate answer on how a king should ideally behave and act can be as long as a whole chapter of Manu Smriti.

> Manu Smriti 8.172. By taking his due, by preventing the confusion of
> the castes (varna), and by protecting the weak, the power of the king
> grows, and he prospers in this (world) and after death.
>
> 7.88. Not to turn back in battle, to protect the people, to honour the Brahmanas, is the best means for a king to secure happiness.

A king should be humble and must not be boastful of his power.

> 7.40. Through a want of modesty many kings have perished, together with their belongings; through modesty even hermits in the forest have
> gained kingdoms.
>
> 7.41. Through a want of humility Vena perished, likewise king Nahusha, Sudas, the son of Pigavana, Sumukha, and Nemi.
>
> 7.42. But by humility Prithu and Manu gained sovereignty, Kubera the position of the Lord of wealth, and the son of Gadhi the rank of a
> Brahmana.

Sri Rama (of Ramayana), who is considered as the role model of a perfect ruler, was very humble.